# Japanese demonyms for each other

Tags: slang, demonyms

In many cultures people will make nicknames for the residents of a certain region, for example Cockneys / Brummies in Britain, or Yankees / Hillbillies in the US.

Are there any common nicknames Japanese people will call each other? I have so far only found 才六{さいろく} and 東男{あづまをとこ}, but both of these seem to be quite old fashioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We actually have **so many**, but the ones that are nationally known would include (going roughly from north to south):

・道産子{どさんこ} - Hokkaido

・水戸{みと}っぽ - City of Mito, Ibaraki Prefecture

・江戸{えど}っ子{こ} - Tokyo

・浜{はま}っ子 - Yokohama

・浪速{なにわ}っ子 - Osaka

・土佐{とさ}っ子 - Kouchi Prefecture

・博多{はかた}っ子 - Fukuoka

・薩摩隼人{さつまはやと} - Kagoshima (male only)

・おごじょ or 薩摩{さつま}おごじょ - Female version of above.

・うちなんちゅう - Okinawa  (This is what Okinawans call themselves.  They call us non-Okinawans やまとんちゅう)

As seen above, many demonyms use the old names of the areas rather than their current names -- 江戸、浪花、土佐, etc.

New arrivals:

・シロガネーゼ - Women of Shirokane area of Tokyo.  Borrowed from "Mila**nese**" in Italian.

・アシヤレーヌ - Women of Ashiya, Hyougo

・ニコタマダム - Married women of Futakotamagawa, Tokyo

***Answered by an 尾張{おわり}っ子 (western half of Aichi Prefecture)

Comment: I very much appreciate this answer!