# Any reason "Naniwa musume" is used to refer to a girl in modern times (as opposed to "Oosaka musme")?

Tags: word-choice, words, culture, history, connotation

Naniwa is an antiquated name for what is now referred to as the Oosaka region (It was called Naniwa around the 1500s last, if I'm not mistaken).

That being said, In Shinya Shokudo S3E04 (released in 2014), a girl from that area is referred to as "Naniwa musume" by the Shokudou owner, and again as such by some other guys. Why is she referred to as such, instead of using "Oosaka musume"? Is there any particular connotation or something I'm missing about "Naniwa"? Or is it kind of like how, sometimes, people like referring to the Northeast United States as "New England"?

[image: moment where girl is called "Naniwa Musume"]

Comment: "Or is it kind of like how, sometimes, people like referring to the Northeast United States as "New England"?" New England is a region, comprised of six states specifically, so there isn't any ambiguity like it seems you're implying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Old prefecture names](https://www.myjapanesehanga.com/home/articles/ancient-provinces-of-japan.html) are still popular as nicknames. Naniwa is nationally known as a nickname for Osaka, just as Edo is still commonly used as the alternative name for Tokyo.

Nicknames for residents of a certain prefecture are also frequently based on these old names. See: [Japanese demonyms for each other](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56813/5010)

While 大阪(の)娘 is also perfectly correct, terms like 江戸っ子 and 浪花娘 are more often used in reference to certain character stereotypes.